# How to output to Blob service with Durable functions

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage, azure-durable-functions

I am new to Azure functons and Durable functions.
I want to write a code that the activity function called by the orchestrator function will compute some value and connect to the Blob service.

How can I modify the code below to output the value generated by the activity function to the Blob service?

The environment I am using is,

- Azure Functions, Durable Functions
- Visual Studio Code
- Python programming model v2

The following is a simplified code I am considering using. Please modify this one.
Incidentally, client functions and orchestration functions may not have much to do with each other

```
import  azure.functions  as  func
import  azure.durable_functions  as  df
import  logging  

app  =  df.DFApp(http_auth_level=func.AuthLevel.ANONYMOUS)  

### client function ###
@app.route(route="orchestrators/client_function")
@app.durable_client_input(client_name="client")
async  def  client_function(req: func.HttpRequest, client: df.DurableOrchestrationClient) -> func.HttpResponse:
    instance_id  =  await  client.start_new("orchestrator", None, {})
    logging.info(f"Started orchestration with ID = '{instance_id}'.")
    await  client.wait_for_completion_or_create_check_status_response(req, instance_id)
    status  =  await  client.get_status(instance_id)
    return  f"output: {status.output}"  

### orchestrator function ###
@app.orchestration_trigger(context_name="context")
def  orchestrator(context: df.DurableOrchestrationContext) -> dict:
    test  =  yield  context.call_activity("main", "")
    return {"Test": test} 

### activity function ###
@app.blob_output(arg_name="outputblob",
                path="newblob/test.txt",
                connection="BlobStorageConnection")

@app.activity_trigger(input_name="blank")
def  main(blank: str, outputblob: func.Out[str]):
    string  =  "Data is successfully Inserted"
    logging.info(f'Python Queue trigger function processed {len(string)} bytes')
    outputblob.set(string)
    return  "Completed"
```

local_setting.json

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
  "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
  "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "python",
  "AzureWebJobsFeatureFlags": "EnableWorkerIndexing",
  "BlobStorageConnection": "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountNa***"
  }
}
```

error message
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ntbl4.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*I have used the below code to write the value generated by activity function into blob storage.*

**`function_app.py`**

```cs
import  azure.functions  as  func
import  azure.durable_functions  as  df
import  logging  

app  =  df.DFApp(http_auth_level=func.AuthLevel.ANONYMOUS)  

### client function ###
@app.route(route="orchestrators/client_function")
@app.durable_client_input(client_name="client")
async  def  client_function(req: func.HttpRequest, client: df.DurableOrchestrationClient) -> func.HttpResponse:
instance_id  =  await  client.start_new("orchestrator", None, {})
logging.info(f"Started orchestration with ID = '{instance_id}'.")
await  client.wait_for_completion_or_create_check_status_response(req, instance_id)
status  =  await  client.get_status(instance_id)
return  f"output: {status.output}"  

### orchestrator function ###
@app.orchestration_trigger(context_name="context")
def  orchestrator(context: df.DurableOrchestrationContext) -> dict:
test  =  yield  context.call_activity("main", "")
return {"Test": test} 

### activity function ###
# I want to calculate the value and output it to the bound service.
@app.blob_output(arg_name="outputblob",
path="newblob/test.txt",
connection="BlobStorageConnection")

@app.activity_trigger(input_name="blank")
def  main(blank: str, outputblob: func.Out[str]):
string  =  "Data is successfully Inserted"
logging.info(f'Python Queue trigger function processed {len(string)} bytes')
outputblob.set(string)
return  "Completed"
```

**`local.settings.json`**

```json
{
"IsEncrypted": false,
"Values": {
"AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
"FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "python",
"AzureWebJobsFeatureFlags": "EnableWorkerIndexing",
"BlobStorageConnection": "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=**********"
}
}
```

Fetch the value of connection string as shown below and add it in local.settings -

[image]

**`Output:`**

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you.
[connection="BlobStorageConnection"] in the activity function
and in local.settings.json
["BlobStorageConnection": "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=**********"]
are set to the same value?

Comment: @TY00 Yes, I am passing the value of `BlobStorageConnection` in `"BlobStorageConnection": "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=**********"`

Comment: I copied and pasted all of function_app.py and local.settings.json and changed only one place in the connection string. I also set up requirements.txt. However, [Orchestrator function 'orchestrator' failed: Activity function 'main' failed: Storage account connection string 'AzureWeb Make sure that it is a defined App Setting. What is the cause?

Comment: @TY00 Are you passing the connection string in local.settings file and referring it in function_app.py ?

Comment: There were also different error statements.
[Orchestrator function 'orchestrator' failed: Activity function 'main' failed: Storage account connection string 'AzureWebJobsBlobStorageConnection' does not exist. Make sure that it is a defined App Setting. ]

Comment: Yes. I think it is referring to.
Since I can't paste the code I'm using in the comments, how about posting a new question and having people look at my code there?
I will push Good button this question.

Comment: @TY00 please make sure connection string name passed in function_app and in local.settings file should be same

Comment: Question has been revised.
What I'm currently using is the code described in the question.
I believe it is referenced correctly.

Comment: @TY00 what error you are getting now? please share the screenshot

Comment: I also added error messages to the question

Comment: @TY00 are you using `AzureWebJobsBlobStorageConnection` anywhere in the code?

Comment: The code provided is all.
I don't know what [AzureWebJobsBlobStorageConnection] is, so I assume I'm not using it.

Comment: The storage where I am setting the connection string is the storage used by the task hub in "function_app.py".

Comment: @TY00 are you running this function locally or in in function app?

Comment: When executed in the local environment, the following error message appears and the program is forced to terminate.
[There was an error performing a read operation on the Blob Storage Secret Repository.
Core: Could not connect because it was denied by the target computer (127.0.0.1:10000). (127.0.0.1:10000).]

Comment: @TY00 Enable Azurite: Start like [this](https://i.imgur.com/Q8kgekp.png), then run your function

Comment: When enabled, [output: {'Test': 'Completed'}] was displayed in the local environment!!!

Comment: @TY00 You can check the Blob storage too, you will see a container and a blob are created

Comment: I was able to run it in my local environment, but after deploying it, I am getting the same error in the cloud environment.

Comment: @TY00 For portal, add the connection string like [this](https://i.imgur.com/E9W5Ikz.png) in function app

Comment: All done without incident!
Your help is much appreciated!
Thank you so much!